# Липкий хэдер прячет табы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

При изменении активного таба сортировки ответов табы скрываются под заголовком, если у него включена липучесть:

Sticky header spoils tabs.
When you click tab with answers sort order, tabs go up and become hidden by sticky header:

[image: скриншот]

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Исправление будет доступно в следующей сборке.